# how to convert 'std::vector<double>' to 'double' in initialization

Tags: c++, vector, stl, quicksort

I'm trying to make quicksort program. I just couldn't understand why and how this error is coming. I've tried every method online but I'm unable to catch the issue. If I'm doing this with array in place of vector, I'm getting correct output but with vector error is coming.

My errors are:

`.\quicksort.cpp:7:28: error: cannot convert 'std::vector<double>' to 'double' in initialization`

`double pivot = values[end];`

`.\quicksort.cpp:10:19: error: no match for 'operator<=' (operand types are 'std::vector<double>' and 'double')`

`if (values[i] <= pivot) {`

How to convert the `vector<double>` to double then?

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int partition(vector<double> *values, int start, int end) {
  double pivot = values[end];
  int pIndex = start;
  for (int i=start; i<end; i++) {
    if (values[i] <= pivot) {
      swap(values[i], values[pIndex]);
      pIndex++;
    }
  }
  swap(values[pIndex], values[end]);
  return pIndex;
}

void quicksort(vector<double> *values, int start, int end) {
  if (start<end) {
    int pIndex;
    pIndex = partition(values, start, end);
    quicksort(values, start, pIndex-1);
    quicksort(values, pIndex+1, end);
  }
}


int main() {
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  vector<double> values(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> values[i];
  }
  quicksort(values, 0, n-1);
  for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
    cout<<values[j]<<" ";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

How to rectify these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References not pointers

```
int partition(vector<double>& values, int start, int end) {

void quicksort(vector<double>& values, int start, int end) {
```

If you used a pointer (but you shouldn't) the correct code would be

```
double pivot = (*values)[end];
```

Pointers are not the same as the things they are pointing to, you have to use `*` or `->` to get at the object that a pointer points to. You don't have to do this with references.

Comment: The solution worked. What is the main difference between pointers and references? How to know which to use when? Also, when I was using arrays it worked but not with vectors. How?

Comment: Arrays are special, they are automatically converted to pointers when passed to a function. This rule does not apply to **any** other kind of object, so forget about arrays. As for the difference between pointers and references I'm sure you can google that (it's a bigger topic than I can address in this comment), and the choice of which to use is sometimes a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

- You have a C++ compiler so use it, send Reference to your object instead of pointer:

```cpp
void  quicksort(vector<double> &values, const int start, const int end);
int  partition(vector<double> &values, const int start, const int end)
```

And your compile time error gone, with pointer to the object you need to call your function like this:

```cpp
quicksort(&values, 0, n - 1);
```

Because you need it's address (actually your pointer need it).

And you need to use `operator[]` of `std::vector` which is first need to get `std::vector` object from pointer to it:

```cpp
double  pivot  = (*values)[end];
```

As you see it's ugly and could be complex, So it's better to use References instead of pointer in those situations.

Answer (score 0):

Your partition and quicksort functions take pointers as parameters not reference values.

Your functions should be declared as such:

```cpp
int partition(vector<double> &values, int start, int end)
void quicksort(vector<double> &values, int start, int end)
```

The reason you are getting the error is that since the values parameter is a pointer when you use the array accessor (`[i]`) it assumes that values is an array of vectors and returns a vector not a double.

Answer (score 0):

you should pass `vector<double>&` to your function instead of `vector<double>*`, i.e. pass by reference instead of pass by pointer. If passing by pointer, then you need to access the elements of the vector with `->[index]`.